# Api Gateway + Cognito + Lambda + DynamoDB user access validation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

Let's say I have about 20 different types of resources in my dynamodb, which are premium features. Now for each resource I want to validate access of a particular user, I mean an user "buys" access to particular resource - how should I store its access? In. e.g. dynamodb table, and search the table for every user request to a particular resource? Or e.g. should I use Cognito and custom attributes? And store e.g. resource id and timestamp till a particular user has access? Or create a group in cognito for each resource and check if a particular user is assigned to the group? Or is there any other good, cheap way to validate user access?

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use cognito if you want cheap.
You can perfectly setup authentication and authorization yourself. Use dynamodb (or RDS) to keep track of users and permissions.

With cognito it's rather easier to setup, you can assign roles to users, allow or deny access to tables, and know perfect which cognito user uses which resource..

Comment: I'm not exactly a fan of Cognito, but why wouldn't you use it "if you want cheap"? It has a non-expiring free-tier of 50,000 monthly active users.